# Cannot distinguish between request parameters due to the use of a base model, resulting in null method parameters

Tags: inheritance, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am currently using WSO2 AM to convert my SOAP APIs to REST, but I have encountered a significant problem. In my gateway, the request parameters for all methods are inherited from a base model and are not organized within a single model. As a result, WSO2 is unable to differentiate between request parameters, causing all parameters received by my method to be null. I would appreciate any guidance on how to address this issue.